# Small Basic Token is incorrect

Tags: token, smallbasic

I'm writing a code using LitDev extension. That is my code:

```
GraphicsWindow.BackgroundColor = "blue"
button = Controls.AddButton("Hej", 100, 100)
LDControls.SetButtonStyle(button, "Blue", "", "", "", "", "", 0, "False")
```

And after turning my app on I'm getting an error:
<>c__DisplayClass396_0.b__0 : Token is incorrect.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The parameters must be defined with colors, apparently no default**

```
      GraphicsWindow.BackgroundColor = "gray"
      myButton = Controls.AddButton(" H e j ", 200, 200)
      LDControls.SetButtonStyle(myButton, "Blue", "Yellow", "Brown", "White", "Orange", "Black" , 3 , "False")
```